# jquery div id is not taking on dynamic div id creation

Tags: jquery

I am creating a set of dynamic divs

Let div id is  div1 div2 div3 etc

in my function for getting div id am concatinating

```
var divid= 'div'+1
var divid= 'div'+2
```

etc.

if i call jquery slide down

```
$('#div1').slideDown('slow');
```

Its working ,but  if i use

```
$('#divid').slideDown('slow');
```

Its not working . Why? divid is having same value.. What i am missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$('#divid').slideDown('slow');
```

to

```
$('#'+divid).slideDown('slow');
```

String literal v.s variable issue

Comment: exactly...hmm.. why i miss that... sad but true

Answer (score 3):

In the example you show:

```
$('#divid')
```

`divid` is interpreted as a *literal string*, not a variable.

What you are probably looking for is

```
$('#'+divid)
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is looking for a div with the id 'divid', that's what `$('#divid')` does.  What you want is to use the variable divid to search, you need to do `$('#'+divid)`.

Answer (score 0):

`divid` is string not variable in your case.

```
$("#"+divid).slideDown("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divid= 'div'+1
var divid2= 'div'+2 


jQuery('#'+divid).slideDown('slow'); 
you have to pass proper selector to jquery
```